# Why is the callback not reached straight away?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Please see the code below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SynchronizationContext sc;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            sc = SynchronizationContext.Current;

            var _threadStart = new ThreadStart(LongProcess);
            var _thread = new Thread(_threadStart);
            _thread.Start();
            //simulate a time consuming operation.
            for (long l=0; l<100000000000000; l++)
            {

            }

        }

        private void callback()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reached callback method");
        }

        private void LongProcess()
        {
            sc.Post(
                    (o) => callback(), null);
        }
    }
```

The callback function is only reached after the Form1 constructor has finished. Is it possibe for the callback to be reached whilst the constructor is still running?

Comment: This depends on the synchronization context.  If the `sc` is restricted to the current thread (which I believe is the case for WinForms), and the constructor is running on the same context then it'll be queued and must wait until the constructor (and caller) returns control.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, you've queued it back to the same thread (via `sc.Post`) and it cannot run until that thread gets a chance to pump messages.

You've moved one time-consuming operation to a background thread, why not do the same for the second one?

Comment: "You've moved one time-consuming operation to a background thread"  No they haven't.  The only thing they moved to a background thread is the scheduling of work to run on the UI thread.

Comment: @Servy: The function is named `LongProcess`.  Obviously the actual work is left out to make the example minimal and self-contained.